# Arduino connection with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-06, l298n, l293d

I have 3 Arduino boards, let's call them be A, B, C. I'm connecting A with a bluetooth module and I'm getting the input from the bluetooth module.
Now I want to send output from A using the digital pins and I want the output of A to be the inputs of B and C. The output sent from A will be based on voice input from the bluetooth module. The inputs of B and C will provide output signals to L293D and L298N motor drives. I have only one bluetooth module. Is this possible? Please let me know, it's urgent. I'm working on a project.

Comment: No. Simple as that

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect ABC with wires, then it is easy - I use Wire library to send a lot of messages to net of many Arduinos.

Also other protocols are avaiable, like SPI, software serial, ... or if the communication is extremely easy (like just On/Off), then digitalWrite()/digitalRead() would work really easy.

I see the voice input to be more difficult in Arduino-size computers (voice recognition is not easy), but maybe you can process the voice before sending BT (on PC/tablet/phone/...) and then the BT would transfer only simple commands and it would be no problem at all.

If there is something I missed, you may write more, where you see the main problem.